# Remove HTML tag and keep text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to remove the HTML blockquote tag, but keep the text? Basically, if in my code was `<blockquote>Hello!</blockquote>`, I'd want it to display as `Hello!` - I don't know if there's a way to filter the blockquotes out or just clone the text, but an answer would be quite helpful!

Comment: So you want to remove the HTML tag, and keep the text?

Answer (score 11):

Use [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) with [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$("blockquote").contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: check the post for an update that I would appreciate answered too.

Comment: @JamesCharless If the answer convinced you please tick it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.html()` to achieve this

```
$("blockquote").html()
```

Check out [this running example](http://jsfiddle.net/SpykC/)